# how to create treeview in mvvm silverlight

Tags: xaml, mvvm, silverlight-4.0

Can anyone have simple procedure to create tree view in silverlight mvvm.
Can we write tree view in silverlight mvvm without the using system.Interactivity.dll or without triggers.

Comment: Did you have a look at the treeview control? The ViewModel has to provide an hierarchical datastructure and that's it. What do triggers and the interactivity assembly have to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the sample here http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Using-the-TreeView-control-in-Silverlight-4.aspx Also why are you not wanting to use Interactivity dll? It is one of the best thing in Silverlight in my opinion. Triggers keep the code very clean.